# ActionScript 3 - startTouchDrag X axis only?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, touch, draggable

I have an object on the stage called, square_mc, currently I have a function which is using the startTouchDrag method to move my object wherever the user touches the screen. But I dont want my object to move on the Y axis (Up and down) is this possible.

Heres my code...

```
//touchpoint
var touchPoint;

//When user touchs stage fun touchDown function.
stage.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, touchDown ); 

//When the user stops touching the screen run.
stage.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END, touchUp );     

    //When user touchs on screen run. 
    function touchDown(evt:TouchEvent):void
     {

        //TouchPoint = localX.
        var touchPoint = evt.localX;

        //Start the touch drag on the square_mc, moves where the user touche   the stage.
        square_mc.startTouchDrag(evt.touchPointID);

        trace("User touched");

    } // end function


    function touchUp(evt:TouchEvent):void
    {

        //More code will be written.
    }
```

Many thanks

Comment: [Please read the documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Sprite.html#startTouchDrag()) `startTouchDrag() has 3 parameters. The third one defines a Rectangle that describes the allowed movement of your dragged object. So in order to only allow horizontal movement, pass a Rectangle with a width of whatever and a height of 0 (or 1, forgot which one is better.)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Slightly confused how to implement though

Comment: Why? Lets say you want the user to be able to move your square_mc 100 px to the right from the initial position of your target, then you would write something like `square_mc.startTouchDrag(evt.touchPointID, false, new Rect(square_mc.x,square_mc.y,100,0));`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, just trying out your example would I place this in the touch down function ? I'm getting ERROR  call to undefined method on react

Comment: Sorry, I meant to write `new Rectangle(..`. And yes, replace your previous startTouchDrag function call with my suggestion.

Comment: Sorry to keep bugging you. This is what have        square_mc.startTouchDrag(evt.touchPointID, false, new Rectangle(square_mc.x,square_mc.y,100,0));    Still getting error from it. I think I understand what your trying to achieve though

Comment: Yeah Sorry, it's been a while since i've used AS3, and I can't debug it now because of a new workstation. What's the error though? If it still can't find Rectangle, you probably haven't imported it. Either `import flash.geom.Rectangle;` should be at the top of your file or write `new flash.geom.Rectangle(...` instead. And don't worry, I'm on this site to help, asking follow up questions isn't bugging me ;-)

Comment: WORKED ! Thank you completely forgot to import . (Cant wait to finish with actionscript and move onto something else, driving me crazy)